# Abusive Comment Removal by Moderator

Tags: discussion, mod-abuse

Relevant comments regarding the invalid closure reason by a mod were removed from a question. Can this be looked into by the other mods.

[Found a part on an old FM transmitter used for tuning. What is it?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202378/found-a-part-on-an-old-fm-transmitter-used-for-tuning-what-is-it)

Question was closed as repair when it was clearly and originally identification. Comments stating as much and reopen votes deleted by a mod.

Comment: Comments got moved to chat, and there is a link to the chat room.  Do you see it okay?

Comment: You removed all comments, and just added them back.

Comment: What do you mean "just"?  You have posted this 5 minutes ago.  I have moved them to chat 9 minutes ago.

Comment: The accusatory tone of this question is inappropriate.  It's fair to discuss a decision, ask for the reasoning behind it, and even express your disagreement.  However starting out pretending that it is generally accepted that the action was "abusive", the comments were "relevant", the closure "invalid", and the question was "clearly" something something else is just being obnoxious and whiny.  Grow up.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the edit history, and you'll see this was originally worded as a repair question.

*You* then edited it, instead of the OP, to make it sound less repair-like, and also left a snide comment in the process.  Since the OP didn't do it, it doesn't mean anything, so nothing changed.

Eventually the OP did edit it into a legitimate identification question, but by that time it has already been closed.  That's what happens when you write a crappy question and don't promptly attend to the feedback you get.  Your editing may have also delayed the OP's response, thereby contributing to the question's eventual demise.

Clearing out a lengthy comment chain is one of the things mods do, and is necessary to keep the site clean.  After all, comments are not for adding content, so it should be fine to clear them after the person they are addressed to has seen them.  Long-lasting information should either be added to the question, written as a answer, or discussed here on meta.

Comment: The ""feedback"" was an instant close. OP had no chance to reply or fix before that. And a repair question typical means they are asking how to fix something. Both the original title and question were asking for an id, not how to fix.

Comment: @Passe: When you post crap, your question gets closed.  Sometimes its too fast to do anything about, sometimes not.  Oh well.  If you don't like that, don't post crap.  And no, the original question was worded like a repair question (*"what part is this so I can replace it to fix this unit?"*).

Comment: "What part is this" is Identification.

Comment: @Passe: But again, it wasn't about electrical engineering, wanting to understand the circuit, or to learn something.  It was about fixing a broken unit.  Give it up already.  This question was rightly closed.  The decision has been made, and most people agree with it.  Get over it.

Comment: SE is *designed* such that users can edit questions to make them better.  No OP is *owed* such service, but at some level, contributors serve the community and the archive, not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Nick used the "move all comments to chat" option to delete all the comments and move them to a chat room. This action action is normally reserved for moving long discussions to a more appropriate venue.

After that, Nick purged the question from the reopen review queue.

Comment: And purging a question from the review queue is in line with proper moderation steps? Actively preventing a question from being handled by the community?

Comment: Or rolling back edits meant to improve the question.

Comment: @Passerby  Or editing question that you are currently complaining about.  So that it... appears better.

Comment: You mean the edit that happened minutes before you decided to erase comments and delete it from the reopen queue? The edit that happened before I had reason to complain?

Comment: Then don't complain that I have rolled it back.